# How to apply a working GEE code to many line segments with unique ID's (river width application using GSW dataset)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have been working on a GEE code to estimate effective river widths using the Global Surface Water (GSW) dataset.

The code uses two publicly available datasets (GSW and HydroLakes_polygons) and an updated river network uploaded as a sharable asset (Updated_river_network).

The *purpose* of the code is to estimate effective river widths along the demonstration river network for different water occurrences (i.e., 1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50%) using the GSW dataset.

The code does this by creating a buffer around line segments on the river network, estimates the area of water pixels, then divides the water area by the line segment length to calculate the “effective width”.

Currently, the code can only be applied to a single line segment at any one time (defined by the unique segment ID at L95).  The code runs successfully, and effective widths for each water occurrence are written to a .csv file.

**The working code is available here**: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fe2da4d7e75d94a46bb826f862c350b4

and an extract of it:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Apply RODEO for effective river widths 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Applies the RODEO workflow to estimate effective river widths for the selected segment.

var connected_mask = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([max_river_clip_unmasked_50, max_river_clip_unmasked_40, max_river_clip_unmasked_30, max_river_clip_unmasked_20, max_river_clip_unmasked_10, max_river_clip_unmasked_1]);
//print(connected_mask)

var reach_length = ee.Number(reach_select.first().get('length'));
print(reach_length, 'Length of line segment [m]')

var effective_width_2 = function(con){
  var sum = con.select('channelMask').eq(1).reduceRegions({
  collection: reach_geom_buffer, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
  })
  return(sum.copyProperties(con).set({'system:time_start': con.get('system:time_start')}))
}

var eff_width2 = connected_mask.map(effective_width_2)
//print(eff_width2)

var eff_width2 = eff_width2.map(function(f){
  var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(f).first()
  return (ee.Feature(ft).copyProperties(f).set({'system:time_start': f.get('system:time_start')}))
})

//Function to convert number of river pixels into river area. 
var Area_fun = function (feature) {
  var d = ee.Number(feature.get('sum'));
  var id = feature.getString('system:index').slice(0,24)
  return feature.set({Area: ee.Number(d).multiply(900), id: id, 'system:time_start':feature.get('system:time_start'), 'length': reach_length});
}

var area_map = eff_width2.map(Area_fun)
//print(area_map)

var fc_test = area_map

//Function to calculate effective width. 
var effW_fun = function (feature) {
  var Area = ee.Number(feature.get('Area'))
  var Length = ee.Number(feature.get('length'))
  return feature.set({Effective_width: Area.divide(Length)});
}
var testing = fc_test.map(effW_fun)
var output = testing

//print(output)


// Add segment ID to output feature collection

var output_final = output.map(function(ft){
  return ee.Feature(ft).set('Segment_ID', segment_select)
})

print(output_final, 'Outputs - including effective widths [m]')



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Output effective widths to .csv
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Output to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: output_final,
    selectors: ['Segment_ID', 'Effective_width'],
    description: ('GSW_effective_river_widths_' + segment_select),
    fileNamePrefix: ('GSW_effective_river_widths_' + segment_select),
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

My *goal* is to upscale the analyses and apply the code to lots of unique segment ID’s for large river catchments (i.e., hundreds of thousands of unique segment ID’s).

I am unsure how to take the next step.  Could I map / iterate the code over a list of unique segment ID’s?  Or could the current code be modified and applied to multiple line segments with unique ID’s at the same time?

The list of unique segment ID’s is included at the end of the code (L273-556).

Ideally, the output would be a single .csv file that contains the unique segment ID and the effective widths at different water occurrences (1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50%) for all of the segments in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to map **list_segment_IDs** and export **finalOutput** Feature Collection as follows. This produces 283*6 (GSW ocurrence) = 1698 records for **Segment_ID** and   **Effective_width**.

```
var list_segment_IDs = [
10466, 10467, 10468, 10500, 10501, 10502, 10503, 10504, 10505, 10506, 10507, 10530, 10531, 10532, 10533,
10534, 10535, 10536, 10537, 10538, 10539, 10540, 10541, 10542, 10544, 10545, 10546, 10547, 10548, 10549,
10564, 10565, 10566, 10567, 10568, 10569, 10570, 10571, 10572, 10573, 10574, 10575, 10576, 10577, 10578,
10579, 10580, 10581, 10582, 10625, 10626, 10627, 10628, 299485, 299486, 299487, 299488, 301367, 301368, 301369,
301370, 301371, 301372, 301373, 301374, 301375, 301376, 301377, 301378, 301379, 302454, 302455, 302456, 302457,
302458, 302459, 302460, 302461, 302462, 302521, 302522, 302523, 302525, 302526, 302527, 302528, 302529, 302530,
302531, 302532, 302777, 302778, 302779, 302780, 302781, 302782, 302783, 302784, 302785, 302786, 302787, 303652,
303653, 303654, 303655, 303656, 305381, 305382, 305383, 305384, 305385, 305548, 305549, 306612, 306613, 306614,
306615, 306616, 306617, 306618, 306619, 306620, 306621, 306622, 306623, 306624, 306625, 306626, 306627, 306628,
306629, 306630, 306631, 306632, 308145, 308146, 308147, 308148, 308149, 563761, 563762, 563763, 563764, 563789,
563790, 563791, 563792, 563793, 563794, 563795, 563796, 563797, 563803, 563804, 563805, 563806, 563807, 563848,
563849, 563850, 563851, 563852, 563853, 563854, 563855, 563919, 563920, 563921, 563922, 563923, 563924, 563925,
563926, 563927, 563928, 563929, 563930, 563931, 563932, 563933, 563934, 564104, 564105, 564106, 564107, 564108,
564109, 564110, 564111, 564112, 564113, 564169, 564170, 564199, 564200, 564201, 564202, 564203, 564204, 564205,
564206, 564207, 564208, 564255, 564301, 564302, 564303, 564304, 564357, 564358, 564359, 564409, 564410, 564411,
564412, 564413, 564414, 564415, 564416, 564417, 564418, 564419, 564420, 564493, 564494, 564495, 564496, 564497,
564498, 564499, 564500, 564509, 564510, 564511, 564512, 564513, 564514, 564515, 564516, 564517, 564518, 564719,
564720, 564721, 564722, 564734, 564735, 564826, 564827, 564828, 631061, 631062, 631063, 631065, 631066, 631067,
631068, 631069, 631161, 631162, 631229, 631230, 631245, 631246, 631249, 631250, 631251, 631252, 631253, 631254,
631289, 631290, 631291, 631292, 631293, 631294, 631295, 631296, 631299, 631300, 631308, 631309, 631407]; 

print('List of unique IDs to apply code over', list_segment_IDs);

var finalOutput = list_segment_IDs.map(function (ele) {

 var segment_select = ele; //563852
 var reach_select = Updated_river_network.filter(ee.Filter.eq('cat', segment_select));
 var reach_geom = reach_select.geometry(); 
 //print('Segment information', reach_select);

 // Generate the flat cap buffer
 var fc = reach_select;
 var bufferSize = (ee.Number(reach_select.first().get('river_widt')).multiply(2.5));
 var buffers = fc.map(function(f) { return f.buffer(bufferSize); });
 var reach_geom_buffer = fc.map(function(f) { return bufferButtCap(f, bufferSize); });
 reach_geom_buffer = reach_geom_buffer.geometry();

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // Process the GSW data 
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 // Process the GSW data (i.e., gets water layers with at 50%, 40%, 30%, 20%, 10% and 1% occurrence). 
 // Modifies based on connectivity to the updated river network, and removes known lake areas using HydroLakes

 var scale = 30;

 // Converts the HydroLakes polygons to an image.
 var Hydrolakes = HydroLakes_polygons
   .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['Lake_type']))
   .reduceToImage({
     properties: ['Lake_type'],
     reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
 });

 // Applies unmasking and converts 0s to 1s (and vice versa). 
 Hydrolakes = Hydrolakes.unmask();
 var Hydrolakes_not = Hydrolakes.not();

 // Processes the GSW data using the specified occurrnces.

 // 50%
 var max_clip_50 = GSW_occurrence.gte(50).rename('waterMask');
 var max_no_Hydrolake_50 = max_clip_50.updateMask(Hydrolakes_not);
 var max_river_max_50 = ExtractChannel(max_no_Hydrolake_50, reach_select, 10000);
 var max_river_clip_50 = max_river_max_50.select('channelMask').clip(reach_geom_buffer);
 var max_river_clip_unmasked_50 = max_river_clip_50.unmask();

 // 40%
 var max_clip_40 = GSW_occurrence.gte(40).rename('waterMask');
 var max_no_Hydrolake_40 = max_clip_40.updateMask(Hydrolakes_not);
 var max_river_max_40 = ExtractChannel(max_no_Hydrolake_40, reach_select, 10000);
 var max_river_clip_40 = max_river_max_40.select('channelMask').clip(reach_geom_buffer);
 var max_river_clip_unmasked_40 = max_river_clip_40.unmask();

 // 30%
  var max_clip_30 = GSW_occurrence.gte(30).rename('waterMask');
  var max_no_Hydrolake_30 = max_clip_30.updateMask(Hydrolakes_not);
  var max_river_max_30 = ExtractChannel(max_no_Hydrolake_30, reach_select, 10000);
  var max_river_clip_30 = max_river_max_30.select('channelMask').clip(reach_geom_buffer);
  var max_river_clip_unmasked_30 = max_river_clip_30.unmask();

  // 20%
  var max_clip_20 = GSW_occurrence.gte(20).rename('waterMask');
  var max_no_Hydrolake_20 = max_clip_20.updateMask(Hydrolakes_not);
  var max_river_max_20 = ExtractChannel(max_no_Hydrolake_20, reach_select, 10000);
  var max_river_clip_20 = max_river_max_20.select('channelMask').clip(reach_geom_buffer);
  var max_river_clip_unmasked_20 = max_river_clip_20.unmask();

  // 10%
  var max_clip_10 = GSW_occurrence.gte(10).rename('waterMask');
  var max_no_Hydrolake_10 = max_clip_10.updateMask(Hydrolakes_not);
  var max_river_max_10 = ExtractChannel(max_no_Hydrolake_10, reach_select, 10000);
  var max_river_clip_10 = max_river_max_10.select('channelMask').clip(reach_geom_buffer);
  var max_river_clip_unmasked_10 = max_river_clip_10.unmask();

  // 1%
  var max_clip_1 = GSW_occurrence.gte(1).rename('waterMask');
  var max_no_Hydrolake_1 = max_clip_1.updateMask(Hydrolakes_not);
  var max_river_max_1 = ExtractChannel(max_no_Hydrolake_1, reach_select, 10000);
  var max_river_clip_1 = max_river_max_1.select('channelMask').clip(reach_geom_buffer);
  var max_river_clip_unmasked_1 = max_river_clip_1.unmask();


  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Apply RODEO for effective river widths 
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Applies the RODEO workflow to estimate effective river widths for the selected segment.

  var connected_mask = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([max_river_clip_unmasked_50, max_river_clip_unmasked_40, max_river_clip_unmasked_30, max_river_clip_unmasked_20, max_river_clip_unmasked_10, max_river_clip_unmasked_1]);
  //print(connected_mask)

  var reach_length = ee.Number(reach_select.first().get('length'));
  //print('Length of line segment [m]', reach_length);

  var effective_width_2 = function(con){
    var sum = con.select('channelMask').eq(1).reduceRegions({
    collection: reach_geom_buffer, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
  });
    return(sum.copyProperties(con).set({'system:time_start': con.get('system:time_start')}));
  };

  var eff_width2 = connected_mask.map(effective_width_2);
  //print(eff_width2)

  eff_width2 = eff_width2.map(function(f){
    var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(f).first();
    return (ee.Feature(ft).copyProperties(f).set({'system:time_start': f.get('system:time_start')}));
  });

  //Function to convert number of river pixels into river area. 
  var Area_fun = function (feature) {
    var d = ee.Number(feature.get('sum'));
    var id = feature.getString('system:index').slice(0,24);
    return feature.set({Area: ee.Number(d).multiply(900), id: id, 'system:time_start':feature.get('system:time_start'), 'length': reach_length});
  };

  var area_map = eff_width2.map(Area_fun);
  //print(area_map)

  var fc_test = area_map;

  //Function to calculate effective width. 
  var effW_fun = function (feature) {
    var Area = ee.Number(feature.get('Area'));
    var Length = ee.Number(feature.get('length'));
    return feature.set({Effective_width: Area.divide(Length)});
  };

  var testing = fc_test.map(effW_fun);
  var output = testing;

  //print(output)

  // Add segment ID to output feature collection

  var output_final = output.map(function(ft){
    return ee.Feature(ft).set('Segment_ID', segment_select);
  });

  return output_final;

});

//print(finalOutput);

var finalOutput = ee.List(finalOutput).map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.FeatureCollection(ele).toList(ee.FeatureCollection(ele).size());
  
}).flatten();

//print(finalOutput);

//print('Outputs - including effective widths [m]', output_final);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Output effective widths to .csv
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Output to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: ee.FeatureCollection(finalOutput),
    selectors: ['Segment_ID', 'Effective_width'],
    description: 'GSW_effective_river_widths' ,
    fileNamePrefix: 'GSW_effective_river_widths',
    fileFormat: 'CSV',
});
```

Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9bd277765a8250e74498fc0ee1734bb4) only exports CSV file so, you can adapt it for adding some river features for corroboration purpose.

After running complete code and task in GEE code editor, part of obtained CSV (with 1699 records; including name columns) looks as follows:

[image]